# Supported AV Media and Container formats in iOS 5

Tags: ios, macos, ios5

What are the supported Media and Container Formats for Audio and Video in iOS?
I'm looking for information of similar quality like the official Android documentation:

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

But can't seem to find any good information about this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the most simillar I've found. It's not as well organized as the android table, but maybe you could take some info:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html